# MassTransit SessionId by convention

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

I'm looking to add Session ID (for Service Bus) support to my MassTransit setup. In the documentation it states the following:

> The SessionId on published/sent messages can be configured by convention, allowing the same method to be used for messages which implement a common interface type. If no common type is shared, each message type may be configured individually using various conventional selectors. Alternatively, developers may create their own convention to fit their needs.

So ideally I'd like to have something like

```cs
public class BaseEvent
{
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

And then wire it up so events use that common type which is eventually picked up as the Session ID.

I did have a look into the convention documentation, as well as looking at how the `CorrelatedBy<T>` worked but it didn't seem clear to me how to accomplish what I'm after, especially as [there is already](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Configuration/Topology/SessionIdMessageSendTopologyConvention.cs) a convention for it.

Would I need to override that, or add something completely new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/transports/azure-service-bus#sessionid) not clear? You can specify the base type with the convention as shown.

```cs
cfg.Send<BaseEvent>(x =>
{
    x.UseSessionIdFormatter(context => context.Message.SessionId.ToString());
});
```

Comment: For whatever reason, I had it in my head you couldn't do it in that way! Have looked over a lot of the docs over the course of the last week or so, so I probably just ended up thinking the wrong thing.

Thank you for the answer, that's exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Well, it works. The pipelines in MassTransit are polymorphic by default, so any implemented/inherited types are included when messages are sent/published.